# BorderLayout West Center East all Equal width

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

I am adding objects dynamically to panels then adding to the my border layout. I need the West, Center and East all to be equal size. This is what I have so far:

```
static int width = 300;//Screen width
static int height = width / 16 * 9;//Screen height
static int scale = 3;

private JFrame frame;

//player is an object from a Player Class will an arrayList of Items.. 
public void LoadPlayer(Player player){
int count = 1;
for (Items i : player.getAllItems()){
    JPanel jp= new JPanel();
    JLabel jlItem= new JLabel(i.getName());
    BorderLayout bl = (BorderLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout()) ;
    jp.add(jlItem);
    jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    if (bl.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.WEST)  == null){
        mainPanel.add(jp,BorderLayout.WEST);
        jp.setSize(frame.getWidth()/3, height);
        System.out.println("adding item " + count+" to west panel");
    }
    else if (bl.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER)  == null){
        jp.setSize(frame.getWidth()/3, height);
        mainPanel.add(jp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        System.out.println("adding item " + count+" to center panel");
    }
    else if (bl.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.EAST)  == null){
        mainPanel.add(jp.BorderLayout.EAST);
        jp.setSize(frame.getWidth()/3, height);
        System.out.println("adding item" + count+" to east panel");
    }
    count++;
}
}
```

I was hopeful this would work but it didn't. I've done a bit of searching and can't seem to find anything that says you can or can't set the size of the `WEST`, `CENTER` and `EAST` panels. 
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need the West, Center and East all to be equal size..

A single row [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of a [nested layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) will achieve that.

Comment: plus 1 to for being a GC and giving the same answer. I sore it pop up as well. Thanks

Comment: Hi Andrew, just a quick question. Do you know how I would be able to insert into the same grids again from another method? So at the moment I have the items names but latter on I would like to add some more information below the names.. I have made the variable static and tried centerPanel.add(new JLabel"Test") ; andcenterPanel.add(new JLabel"Test",1)   just to see if I could and they didn't work. First add simply added a fourth column.. Any ideas? Edit: I guess one way could be to add 3 JPanel Properties add those to the grid, then edit those...

Comment: *"just a quick question."*  That's (part of) what SO is about.  Why not ask a new question, and add the [tag:static] tag?

Answer (score 2):

You never use the setSize() method on a component. That is the job of the layout manager.

If you want the panels to be the same size you can use a GridLayout.